# SolrNet query not working for Scandinavian characters

Tags: .net, solr, solrnet, tomcat8

When making a query through SolrNet that contains Scandinavian characters like ø, æ, å the query returns no results while queries containing regular words work fine.

The query has been added to the `FilterQueries` collection using the `SolrQueryByField` class with values "ss_content" which is the field name and the values \"søren\" with quoted set to false. even if i test without the "" in søren it doesn't give any results.

When running the same query through Solr Admin page in the browser it works fine.

Am i missing some configuration in  SolrNet which could be causing the issue?

Solr version is 3.6 on Tomcat 8 and is being called from a .Net 4.5 application

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the piece of code that builds the solr query and executes the search request?

Answer (score 1):

Solr Admin page query is a plain html `<form method=get action="#">[...]</form>`, meaning that the browser will automatically URL-Encode all input values - that is why it works from the Admin page.

You need to url-encode parameter values when forming the requests. In .NET 4.5 you can use `WebUtility.UrlEncode(String)`.

Please try to replace the `"søren"` string with  `WebUtility.UrlEncode("søren")` and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

If it's working fine from the admin panel, I would suspect some kind of encoding issue. Use UTF-8 and there should be a Tomcat 8 connector for it you can set called `URIEncoding`. You can also try to use the analyzer to see how your non-Latin character search term is being interpreted by Solr.

Again, it's working from the admin panel, so I'm not sure this will help you, but try adding an `ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory` to whatever fields you're querying against. Your special characters are outside of the 127 "Basic Latin" ASCII block, and Solr appears to handle them in a different way. Here's the docs for the filter: [ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory). Usage looks something like this:

```
<fieldType . . . >
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" />
</fieldType>
```

As a last ditch, "nuclear" option, if it's possible, have you considered using a [MappingCharFilterFactory](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/CharFilterFactories#CharFilterFactories-solr.MappingCharFilterFactory)? It will allow you to normalize your special characters.